# Cut a field and cut again in the result using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

As part of playing with AWK, I am trying to get the MariaDB version number only in the output.

```
# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

# mysql -V | awk -F"-" '{print $1}' | awk '{print $5}'
10.1.48
```

Is there a workaround in AWK to make it shortened, like to avoid awk '{print $5}' again in the third pipe and make everything in single awk?.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `[ -]+` as `FS` meaning 1+ of space or hyphen:

```sh
mysql -V | awk -F '[- ]+' '{print $5}'

10.1.48
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Is that AWK regular expression?.

Comment: Yes it is a standard regex used a field separator

Answer (score 1):

I would replace `'-'` to `' '` with `gsub()` resulting to this line:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48 MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
  $1   $2   $3   $4      $5     $6 ....
```

and print field number 5:

```
# mysql -V | awk '{gsub("-"," "); print $5}'
10.1.48
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex and without hardcoding field number could you please try following. This should be able to catch even version is `10.1.48.1.2`(if in any case its there)

```
echo "10.1.48" | 
awk 'match($0,/([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is that Awk lets you `split` a field again.

```sh
# mysql -V | awk -F"-" '{split($1, n, /[ \t]+/); print n[5] }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab it with `sed`:

```
$ echo 'mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1' |
sed -nE 's/.* ([0-9][0-9.]*)-MariaDB.*/\1/p'
```

Or with GNU grep:

```
$ echo 'mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1' |
ggrep -oP '[0-9][0-9.]*(?=-MariaDB)'
```

Either prints:

```
10.1.48
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `split` to avoid having extra awk instance:

```
# msql -V | awk -F"-" '{ split($1, a, " ") ; print a[4] }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortest `awk` script I could come with:

```
msql -V | awk '{sub("-MariaDB,","");print $5}'
```